# Enabling multiverse/universe repositories?

Tags: updates, software-center, repository, add-apt-repository, multiverse

I was trying to install some packages from the Software Centre, running 14.10 Ubuntu by the way, but it said I had to use the `multiverse` and `universe` repositories. I tried looking for other answers but it didn't work, it said I could install it but this was the outcome:

> check your internet

There was something like:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
```

I can't even use the `apt-get upgrade` command!

Comment: 14.10 is unsupported since **July 23, 2015** and I think you won't get any updates for it any more and you won't be able to install new software. Please see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29. You'll need to upgrade to a supported version or move to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you can enable the `universe` and `multiverse` repositories through the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
```

**But** as you are using 14.10 which is outdated, the official repositories have been moved to a different location and this won't work.

Please upgrade your system! This question will be helpful:
[How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: When I try that it says it has already been enabled for all sources!

Comment: @A.B. Sorry, missed the 14.10 when I wrote the first version. Edited the answer. No, the repositories get moved to an archive-server (old-releases.ubuntu.com) when the release reaches end-of-life.

Comment: @TheKillj0y Instead of writing "Thank you!", you should accept the answer by clicking on the grey tick symbol on the left of it. Also make sure you have invested two minutes of your time into reading our little [tour] page to learn the basics about how AskUbuntu.com works. Thanks!